# Footnotemark after period in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, punctuation

I need footnotes in either the `pages` or `addendum` fields of some of my references.  Since I don't have control over the period appended at the end of those fields, the footnote mark will end up before the period, which is ugly.  See this MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{KandR,
  AUTHOR    = {Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.},
  TITLE     = {{The C Programming Language Second Edition}},
  PUBLISHER = {Prentice-Hall, Inc.},
  YEAR      = {1988},
  ADDENDUM  = {An Addendum$^{\dagger}$}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
  backend=bibtex   % use BibTeX
% backend=biber    % Use biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Hello \cite{KandR}. How are you?
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I'm using BibLaTeX to process by bibliography.

Comment: You could be interested in `\textdagger`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
 \iffieldundef{addendum}
 {\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}}%
 {\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}}}
```

This checks if the field `addendum` is defined. If yes, deletes the final period at the end of the entry.

Obviously you have to manually insert the period in your `addendum` fields.

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{KandR,
  AUTHOR    = {Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.},
  TITLE     = {{The C Programming Language Second Edition}},
  PUBLISHER = {Prentice-Hall, Inc.},
  YEAR      = {1988},
  ADDENDUM  = {An Addendum.$^{\dagger}$}
}
@BOOK{Book,
  AUTHOR    = {Author A.},
  TITLE     = {A title},
  PUBLISHER = {A publisher},
  YEAR      = {1988}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
  backend=bibtex   % use BibTeX
% backend=biber    % Use biber
]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
 \iffieldundef{addendum}
 {\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}}%
 {\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Hello \cite{KandR}. How are you?\cite{Book}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another, easier way, but you can specify some kerning directly in the bibtex file. For instance:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @BOOK{KandR,
        AUTHOR    = {Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.},
        TITLE     = {{The C Programming Language Second Edition}},
        PUBLISHER = {Prentice-Hall, Inc.},
        YEAR      = {1988},
        ADDENDUM  = {An Addendum\kern.1em$^{\dagger}$\kern-.6em},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
backend=bibtex   % use BibTeX
%backend=biber    % Use biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
    Hello \cite{KandR}. How are you?
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibtex file + Kerning]